# What to make of system scans reported by psad

Tags: networking, security, logs, psad

My system logs show that [`psad`](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/) detects scans like this every minute.

```
psad: scan detected: 192.168.1.10 -> 192.168.1.1 udp: [53] udp pkts: 2 DL: 2
```

If the first address is mine, and the second address is my router, then this would be a scan coming from my computer, correct?

Is this anything to worry about?

Comment: What is the output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `nslookup server`

Answer (score 2):

Port 53 is DNS; nothing to worry about unless you peep in with Wireshark and find that the requests are for hosts you don't visit.